# CSS - How to get div on top of background image?

Tags: html, css

I have a background image half the page, and I have a div underneath it which I also want to put a quarter of it above the background image. I tried to put padding-top on the profile class but it doesn't work whilst wrapping background-pic and profile in a div.

CSS:

```
.background-pic{
      background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/825262/pexels-photo-825262.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260');
      height: 60%;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    }

.profile{
  padding-top: 300px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="background-pic">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="profile" style="background-color: grey; height : 300px;">
        <div class="profile-pic">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: specify html and body height as 100%, to see percentage of div height

Comment: https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/mLPzYq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a negative `margin-bottom` to the first element.

```css
.background-pic {
  background-image: url(https://www.placecage.com/600/400);
  height: 400px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: -100px;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 300px;
  background: rgba(10, 150, 10, .4);
}
```

```html
<div class="background-pic"></div>
<div class="content">Profile content</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome man. Every time I can showcase a Nicholas Cage image, it makes my day.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is put a negative margin on the `.profile` element. I cleaned up your HTML and CSS so you could follow this:

```css
.background-pic{
   background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/825262/pexels-photo-825262.jpeg');
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   height: 500px;
   width: 100%;
}

.profile{
  background-color: pink;
  height: 500px; /* optional if you put enough content in */
  margin: -100px auto 0 auto;
  padding: 25px 50px;
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-pic"></div>
<div class="profile">
   Content goes here.
</div>
```

Demo:
https://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/QrNZPz

Answer (score 0):

In CSS of the `.background-pic` add a property `position : absolute`.

In CSS of the `.profile` add property `position : relative`, then change the padding of text inside .profile according to your need.